# SUBSTRING INDEX CONCERN IN MYSQL QUERY

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find if a numeric value is in between a mysql column value.
For example, I have a value 100-101 in a mysql column and I am looking if 101 matches with any. For that, I did a mysql query

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_lookup 
WHERE 
    form_relation ='Parent' 
    AND (
        '101' BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX  (`scale_raw_score`,'-', 1) 
              AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scale_raw_score`,'-', -1) 
    ) 
    AND scale='SCI'
```

But it returned 2 columns

```
1-2
100-101
```

Why it is returning

```
 1-2
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You are comparing **strings** (not **numbers**).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a string comparison, while you actually want to compare numbers. String-wise, `'101`' is indeed between `'1'` and `'2'`

Consider changing this:

```
'101' BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scale_raw_score`,'-', 1) 
      AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scale_raw_score`,'-', -1)
```

To:

```
101 BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX  (`scale_raw_score`,'-', 1) 
    AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scale_raw_score`,'-', -1)
```

Using a number on the left side of `BETWEEN` instead of a string should be sufficient to indicate MySQL that you want to compare values as numbers instead of strings.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d58b8009cd37192a86f64ddc65d5ea8b)**:

```
SELECT '101' BETWEEN '1' AND '2'
```

```
| '101' BETWEEN '1' AND '2' |
| ------------------------: |
|                         1 |
```

```
SELECT 101 BETWEEN '1' AND '2'
```

```
| 101 BETWEEN '1' AND '2' |
| ----------------------: |
|                       0 |
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion is working all good except with the 0 case. When I am trying to check with '0', it is giving unmatched results from my database. So do we need to connider ) as a special case.

Comment: @sruthy123: what is wrong with `0`? You can try this in the fiddlde I provided, it works too: `SELECT 0 BETWEEN '0' AND '102'`

Comment: ` SELECT * FROM hello_lookup WHERE form_relation ='Parent'  AND (0 BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX 
                (`scale_raw_score`,'-', 1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scale_raw_score`,'-', -1) ) AND scale='SCI'`  . It is giving rsults wiyj NULL entries  and `>=102    `

Comment: `0` and `>=102` and some NULL entries

Comment: Please give me a value of `scale_raw_score` with which you get unexected results with `0 BETWEEN ... AND ...`.